# Sequentially execute tasks

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, cmd

I need to **gracefully** terminate (either via .bat or .vbs) a specific app in order to safely overwrite a (read-only) file in its directory and then delete all files in one of its sub-directories.

I had something like this in mind:

```
@echo off
taskkill /t /im App.exe
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul
xcopy /y /r "C:\Some path\My File.ext" "C:\App path"
Del /f /q "C:\App path\App sub-directory\*.*"
```

Rather than waiting a fixed amount of time (5 seconds in the above example) I would like the 2 last commands to be executed **only** when the taskkill is complete (i.e. the app is closed after eventual prompts have been resolved by the user).

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: FTR, your example waits only 4 seconds, because the 1 second delay is due to the interval between 2 echo-requests. ;)

Comment: Hehe... I did not expect you to miss that detail ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In batch you could do it like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=2" %%p in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq App.exe" /fo list ^| find "PID:"') do set pid=%%p

taskkill /t /pid %pid%

:wait
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
tasklist /fi "pid eq %pid%" /fo list | find "PID:"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto wait

xcopy /y /r "C:\Some path\My File.ext" "C:\App path"
del /f /q "C:\App path\App sub-directory\*.*"

endlocal
```

I'd prefer VBScript for this, though.

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'App.exe'"

For Each p In wmi.ExecQuery(query)
  ' p.Terminate would forcibly terminate the process (like "taskkill /t /f")
  sh.Run "taskkill /t /pid " & p.ProcessId, 0, False
Next

Do While wmi.ExecQuery(query).Count > 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists("C:\App path\My File.ext") Then
  fso.DeleteFile "C:\App path\My File.ext", True
End If
fso.CopyFile "C:\Some path\My File.ext", "C:\App path\", True
fso.DeleteFile "C:\App path\App sub-directory\*.*", True
```

Instead of deleting the destination file, you could also remove the read-only flag:

```
Set f = fso.GetFile("C:\App path\My File.ext")
f.Attributes = f.Attributes And Not 1
```

Comment: @AW... Great support as usual, thanks! The .bat is **excellent** but the .vbs returns a Permission Denied Error...Strange actually because the "True" force parameter should take care of the R-O file, right? Probably using the "xcopy.exe" with the /R switch might solve the issue? Thanks again :)

Comment: `CopyFile()` will fail when the destination file has the read-only flag set. You have to delete the file or unset the flag first (see updated answer). `CopyFile()` will also fail with a `Permission Denied` error when the destination is a folder, but the path does not have a trailing backslash.

Comment: The Permission Denied error is now gone **but** (actually I could have mentioned this earlier) the app does not get terminated... The rest of the operation only continues when/if I manually close the app.

Comment: +1, but make sure you update the VBScript to actually terminate the process, instead of looping indefinitely. :)

Comment: @ AW: Many thanks for the **AWesome** support, however as mentioned in my 1st post, I need to **gracefully** terminate the app and the latter .vbs script terminates it forcibly. Could you kindly fix that? Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Hmm... looks like WMI can only forcibly terminate processes. Unless you spawned the process via `Exec()` in the same script you'll probably have to shell out and run `taskkill`. See updated answer.

Comment: Line: 5 Char: 3 Error: Object required: 'sh' Code: 800A01A8

Comment: Sorry, I was quite tired yesterday. I meant to add a line `Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` to avoid re-instantiation of the object, but then forgot. Fixed.